# How to dynamically load a jar in runtime (Not for reflection)

Tags: java, jar, sdk, classloader

I'm using some vendor's SDK that works fine if the JAR is provided by me.
I want to dynamically load the JAR from a custom path that will be provided in properties file / system environment variable.
And load the this JAR, just before executing the class that wraps the SDK code.

I've started to write the following code:
But I'm not sure which method will actually load the class.
Maybe I'm not using the right API for that?
(Using dynamic class path with a script is not an option here, I know . . .)

```
public void load(String path) {
        String className = getClassName();
        if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(path)) {
            return;
        }
        if (initialized) {
            System.out.println("Already loaded classe " + className);
            return;
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("path = " + path);
            URL[] jars = new URL[]{new URL("file", "", path)};
            System.out.println("url = " + jars[0]);
            try (URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(jars)) {
                classLoader.loadClass(className);
                System.out.println("classLoader.loadClass(getClassName()) worked");
                Class.forName(className);
                System.out.println("Class.forName(getClassName()) worked");
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
                System.out.println("ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(getClassName()) worked");

                initialized = true;
                log.debug("Succeeded loading class ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Failed to load SDK from path: {}. Error: {}", path, e.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error to load: " + e.getMessage());
            }




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load SDK from path: {}. Error: {} " + path + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I've tried to use the Java ClassLoader which I'm not sure is the right API here, a colleague insists that it is. (I think that it's only for Reflection use)
I've found also a link about [Java agent](https://cgjennings.ca/articles/java-9-dynamic-jar-loading/)  which I haven't tried yet.

I saw other similar questions, but I want to make sure this ClassLoader is not the right method for our use.
And if so I'll try something else.
Thanks

Comment: The code looks right for your use case. What's the problem?

Comment: @g00se I get 'ClassNotFoundException' in Class.forName(className).

Comment: So this means when you add new jars to location, you need to load it in runtime? . How are you running your jar?

Comment: @SujayMohan right now, I'm getting my JAR as maven dependency (provided) for development purpose. But in a real scenario it has to be dynamically loaded from a variable in runtime, just before executing a class that uses this JAR (TP SDK)

Comment: `Class.forName(string)` uses the current ClassLoader. But you've loaded your jar into a different classloader. Therefore you need to specify that classloader in your `forName` call, using its other overloaded arguments.

Comment: @k314159 I'm not sure that I understood, can you show an example according to my code? thanks!

Comment: @Gonzo How are you running the jars?

Comment: @SujayMohan I have my code in a JAR, it will be a dependency for other maven projects and they will uses its code directly. right now I'm running it from Main method of one of its classes. the flow of the code is reaching a class that uses the third-party JAR (a SDK) and this one should be loaded dynamically from a custom path.

Comment: @Gonzo , So you are using java -jar <jar name> , right?

Comment: @Gonzo Can you try - java -jar <jar name> -cp $<env var name>. Where env var name represents environment variable which has location of the external jars to include.

Comment: @SujayMohan that's not an option . . . I've mentioned it in the the question. We have to load it during runtime

Comment: `new URL("file", "", path)` will fail if certain characters are in the path which are not legal in URLs.  Also, URL constructors are deprecated in recent versions of Java.  Use `Path.of(path).toUri().toURL()` instead.

Comment: @Gonzo you need to call `Class.forName(className, true, classLoader)`. If you don't supply `classLoader` as an argument, then all you've done in the previous step was to load the class into the classLoader, which is pointless unless you actually use that classLoader.

Comment: @k314159 Thanks! this Class.forName(className, true, classLoader) went OK with no warning. But when I'm getting the SDK classes, I get the 'NoClassDefFoundError' :( Looks like something is missing here to actually load those classes to the memory.

Comment: Apparently the SDK we're using is not supporting custom class loader so thanks anyway everybody 